# does JVM skip a temporary generic conversion

Tags: java, generics, jvm, type-erasure

I'm looking for a way to use primitive collections with generic interfaces.

In the case of **IntArray** class and **scenario** function, will JVM create temporary **Integer** objects, or directly pass an **int**?

Elements are stored in a primitive **int[]** and assigned only directly to primitive **int** so leaving this unoptimized, implies unnecessary object creation, just to destroy it in a fraction of second.

```
public class Test {

    private interface Array<E> {
        E get(int index);
        void set(int index, E element);
    }

    private static class GenericArray<E> implements Array<E> {
        private final E[] elements;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public GenericArray(int capacity) {
            this.elements = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        }


        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return elements[index];
        }

        @Override
        public void set(int index, E element) {
            elements[index] = element;
        }
    }

    private static class IntArray<E> implements Array<Integer> {
        private final int[] elements; // primitive int array

        public IntArray(int capacity) {
            this.elements = new int[capacity];
        }


        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return elements[index];
        }

        @Override
        public void set(int index, Integer element) {
            elements[index] = element;
        }
    }

    private static void scenario(Array<Integer> array) {
        int element = 256;
        array.set(16, element);  // primitive int given
        element = array.get(16); // converted directly to primitive int
        System.out.println(element);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array<Integer> genericArray   = new GenericArray<>(64);
        Array<Integer> primitiveArray = new IntArray<>(64);

        scenario(genericArray);
        scenario(primitiveArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: `IntArray` in your case take an `Integer`. Period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have generics over primitive types ([yet](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218)).

Your `IntArray` deals with `Integer` objects, at least at the bytecode level. If we decompile the class, we'll clearly see calls to the boxing `Integer.valueOf` and unboxing `Integer.intValue` methods:

```
javap -c -private Test$IntArray
```

```
  public java.lang.Integer get(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2      // Field elements:[I
       4: iload_1
       5: iaload
       6: invokestatic  #3      // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       9: areturn

  public void set(int, java.lang.Integer);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2      // Field elements:[I
       4: iload_1
       5: aload_2
       6: invokevirtual #4      // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
       9: iastore
      10: return
```

However, JIT compiler has an optimization to eliminate redundant boxing-unboxing pairs: `-XX:+EliminateAutoBox`. The optimization is ON by default, but unfortunately does not always work. Let's see if it works in your case with the help of the JMH benchmark.

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class GenericArrays {

    Array<Integer> genericArray = new GenericArray<>(64);
    Array<Integer> primitiveArray = new IntArray(64);

    int n;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            genericArray.set(i, i + 256);
            primitiveArray.set(i, i + 256);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int getGeneric() {
        return genericArray.get(n++ & 63);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int getPrimitive() {
        return primitiveArray.get(n++ & 63);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsAppend = "-XX:-EliminateAutoBox")
    public int getPrimitiveNoOpt() {
        return primitiveArray.get(n++ & 63);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void setGeneric() {
        genericArray.set(n++ & 63, n);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void setPrimitive() {
        primitiveArray.set(n++ & 63, n);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsAppend = "-XX:-EliminateAutoBox")
    public void setPrimitiveNoOpt() {
        primitiveArray.set(n++ & 63, n);
    }

    private interface Array<E> {
        E get(int index);

        void set(int index, E element);
    }

    static class GenericArray<E> implements Array<E> {
        private final E[] elements;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public GenericArray(int capacity) {
            this.elements = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return elements[index];
        }

        @Override
        public void set(int index, E element) {
            elements[index] = element;
        }
    }

    static class IntArray implements Array<Integer> {
        private final int[] elements;

        public IntArray(int capacity) {
            this.elements = new int[capacity];
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return elements[index];
        }

        @Override
        public void set(int index, Integer element) {
            elements[index] = element;
        }
    }
}
```

When run the benchmark on JDK 14.0.2, I get the following scores (lower is better).

```
Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt     Score     Error   Units
GenericArrays.getGeneric         avgt   20     3,769 ±   0,039   ns/op
GenericArrays.getPrimitive       avgt   20     3,445 ±   0,037   ns/op
GenericArrays.getPrimitiveNoOpt  avgt   20     5,147 ±   0,073   ns/op
GenericArrays.setGeneric         avgt   20    10,491 ±   0,055   ns/op
GenericArrays.setPrimitive       avgt   20     3,896 ±   0,023   ns/op
GenericArrays.setPrimitiveNoOpt  avgt   20     4,078 ±   0,077   ns/op
```

This leads us to two observations:

- Primitive array seems to perform better;
- `EliminateAutoBox` optimization apparently works, since when the optimization is off, the timings are higher.

Now let's verify if the optimization helps to avoid unnecessary allocations.
GC profiler built into JMH (`-prof gc`) will do the job.

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt     Score     Error   Units
GenericArrays.getGeneric:·gc.alloc.rate.norm         avgt   20    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
GenericArrays.getPrimitive:·gc.alloc.rate.norm       avgt   20    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
GenericArrays.getPrimitiveNoOpt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
GenericArrays.setGeneric:·gc.alloc.rate.norm         avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
GenericArrays.setPrimitive:·gc.alloc.rate.norm       avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
GenericArrays.setPrimitiveNoOpt:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
```

Here we see that the allocation rate of `getPrimitive` benchmark is zero. This means, the JVM was able to eliminate allocation of a temporary `Integer` object. When the optimization is off, the allocation rate is expectedly 16 bytes per operation - exactly the size of one `Integer` object.

For some reason, JVM was not able to eliminate boxing in `setPrimitive`. As I've told earlier, the optimization is fragile and does not work in all cases.

However, `setPrimitive` is still a way faster than `setGeneric`. The benefit comes from the fact that storing a primitive is more efficient than storing a reference, because storing a reference typically requires a GC barrier.

Comment: what a beauty yet again. _...typically requires a GC barrier_ - Shenandoah 2.0 to the rescue!

Comment: „*…JVM was not able to eliminate boxing in `setPrimitive`*“ — ***TL;DR*** Translation: (***Q***) „*does JVM skip a temporary generic conversion?*“ (***A***) „*No.It doesn't…*“

Comment: @deduper Not exactly. *Sometimes* JVM eliminates temporary allocations, *sometimes* it does not. This depends on many factors. For example, if I rewrite autoboxing with `primitiveArray.set(index, new Integer(n))`, the allocation will go away in JITted code.

Comment: @Eugene And yes, Shenandoah also adds a barrier code when storing a reference. Even though a barrier is conditional, checking the condition implies additional overhead.

Comment: @apangin that is why I wrote `2.0` where the load reference barrier will not happen for the write.

Comment: @Eugene There *is* an additional overhead of storing a reference comparing to storing an `int` (except for Epsilon GC which is not actually a GC). For new Shenandoah it's just smaller than for Shenandoah 1 or for G1.

Comment: „*…rewrite autoboxing with `primitiveArray.set(index, new Integer(n))`…*“ — Is that „*rewriting autoboxing*“? Or „*refactoring to do **manual boxing**?*“. Don't get me wrong. I'm impressed by your answer. To where you've inspired me to want to learn more about that *JMH* gizmo. So I'm grateful for the detail you went into. Thanks.

Comment: „*Sometimes JVM eliminates temporary allocations, sometimes it does not…*“ — I take your point. Technically you're correct. ***Practically*** speaking, however…Take software where, from a ***practical*** standpoint, success means  boxing/unboxing happens precisely 0X. Where failure means if boxing/unboxing happens even 5% of the time, people could die. In such cases, if the question is: „*does JVM skip a temporary generic conversion?*“ and if you can't answer with 100% certainty: „*Yes! Absolutely!*“. Then I'd hope you'd be intellectually honest enough to admit: „*No. It doesn't*“. Just sayin.

Comment: @apangin why should it be there though? load-reference-barriers takes care of the fact that the object is in "to-space" already, so there should be no barriers for the _store_ to a reference.

Comment: @Eugene SATB barrier is still required.

Comment: @apangin right, but a SATB barrier is needed in the marking phase (this has not changed from G1 or Shenandoah1); what I was referring to was load-reference-barrier which happens in the compactation phase, and for _writes_ this is different between Shenandoah1 vs 2.

Comment: @deduper autoboxing gets desugared to a call to `Integer.valueOf(int)`, which unfortunately is mandated to maintain a cache for the objects representing values in the range -128…+127. This means the method `valueOf` contains a conditional, returning an existing object or constructing a new one. In contrast, `new Integer(int)` unconditionally constructs a new object. So it is a different code construct, not just “manual boxing”.

Comment: „*…a cache for…values in the range -128…+127…*“ — I learned that 4 yrs ago from [*this paragraph within **Boxing Conversion***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7-300). Hence, given *`Integer two`* then *`System.out.println( ( two = 2 ) == Integer.parseInt( "2" ) )`* would print *`true`*. The timestamp on the *`.java`* file in which I proved it to myself for the first time: *`25/12/2016 19:36`* (*Ho, Ho, Ho!*). But I never dug deep down into the JDK's *`Integer`* code to see that it's implemented with a conditional. So TIL. Thx for that @Holger ::thumbsup::

Comment: @deduper `parseInt` returns an `int`, so comparing its result with an `Integer` will always yield a value based comparison. You’d need to do `( two = 2 ) == (Integer)Integer.parseInt( "2" )` to force object identity comparison. Or use `Integer.valueOf(2) == Integer.valueOf("2")` or such alike. Obviously, as long as there isn’t enough heap memory to cache *all* `Integer` object (~16 * 2³² bytes), there must be some sort of conditional behind the scenes. So `new Integer(int)` is actually easier to optimize (by Escape Analysis)…

Comment: „*…`parseInt` returns an `int`…*“ — Fair enough. But my point wasn't to say that my memory of the exact syntax is as fresh as it was when I first learned about it. My point was to say:  *I learned about „…a cache for…values in the range -128…+127…“ **4 yrs ago***.

Answer (score -2):

> „*…does JVM skip a temporary generic conversion…*“

No. It doesn't. It does a [***Boxing Conversion***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)…

> …
>
> ***5.1.7 Boxing Conversion***
>
> *Boxing conversion treats expressions of a primitive type as expressions of a corresponding reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:*
>
> …
>
> - *From type int to type Integer*
>
> …

…And an [***Unboxing Conversion***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)…

> …
>
> ***5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion***
>
> *Unboxing conversion treats expressions of a reference type as expressions of a corresponding primitive type. Specifically, the following eight conversions are called the unboxing conversions:*
>
> …
>
> - *From type Integer to type int*
>
> …

See the [*Java Tutorial's Autoboxing and Unboxing trail*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

> „*…will JVM create temporary **Integer** objects, or directly pass an **int**?…*“

It does both. First the former followed finally by the latter.

> „*…unnecessary object creation, just to destroy it in a fraction of second…*“

The architects at Oracle that design the Java language probably agree with you…

> > „*…The problem with boxing is that it is [ad-hoc] and expensive; extensive work has gone on under the hood to address both of these concerns…*“ — [***Brian Goetz, State of Valhalla, March 2020***](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/valhalla/sov/02-object-model.html#isnt-this-just-boxing-with-a-fancy-new-name)

And they have a solution in mind for your request…

> „*…for a way to use primitive collections with generic interfaces…*“

…If you're patient…

> > „*…We are trying to preserve room for specialized generics as a future feature… We wish to reserve a natural notation in the future for specialized types, such as `List<int>`…*“ — [***Migration: specialized generics, Brian Goetz, State of Valhalla***](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/valhalla/sov/02-object-model.html#migration-specialized-generics)

Specialized generics aren't a thing yet. But you can [*take other early-access features of Valhalla out for a spin today*](https://jdk.java.net/valhalla/).